# NLTK NaiveBayesClassifier training

Tags: python, twitter, nltk

In [this](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/) example I have been following online, the only way to train the classifier given is by training it on a list of good and bad tweets. Is there anyway to train the same classifier on single bad words instead of having to have a example positive and negative tweet.

I feel like training it on solely negative and positive words would provide a lot more data and therefore more accurate results. It is also a lot easier to find a list of negative and positive words versus numerous examples of positive and negative tweets.

Comment: question how are you going to weigh the words if each word comes from a dictionary and a word's frequency is undetermined?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you may use single words rather than sentences.

This way, it will fit the example you have mentioned.

```
pos_tweets = [('love', 'positive'),('good', 'positive')]
neg_tweets = [('hate', 'positive'),('bad', 'negative')]
```